Retrieve "API Permissions" of all Azure AD Application via PowerShell
I am trying to retrieve the list of APIs each application has permissions amongst other information for.
However the following script gives me empty objects.
Script:
# Get all app registrations in the Azure Active Directory
$appRegistrations = Get-AzureADApplication

# Create an empty array to store app registration data
$appRegistrationData = @()

# Iterate over each app registration
foreach ($appRegistration in $appRegistrations) {
    # Retrieve application client ID
    $clientId = $appRegistration.AppId

    # Retrieve object ID
    $objectId = $appRegistration.ObjectId

    # Retrieve display name
    $displayName = $appRegistration.DisplayName

    # Retrieve API permissions (RequiredResourceAccess)
    $apiPermissions = $appRegistration.RequiredResourceAccess | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

    # Retrieve AppRoles, OAuth2Permissions, delegated permissions, and application permissions
    $servicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "AppId eq '$clientId'"

    $appRoles = $servicePrincipal.AppRoles | Select-Object -Property *
    $oauth2Permissions = $servicePrincipal.Oauth2Permissions | Select-Object -Property *
    $delegatedPermissions = $servicePrincipal.DelegatedPermissions | Select-Object -Property *
    $applicationPermissions = $servicePrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.AllowedMemberTypes -contains "Application" }

    # Add the app registration data to the array
    $appRegistrationData += [PSCustomObject]@{
        DisplayName = $displayName
        ClientId = $clientId
        ObjectId = $objectId
        ApiPermissions = $apiPermissions
        AppRoles = $appRoles
        OAuth2Permissions = $oauth2Permissions
        DelegatedPermissions = $delegatedPermissions
        ApplicationPermissions = $applicationPermissions
    }
}

# Output the app registration data
$appRegistrationData | Format-Table -AutoSize

Output for: DelegatedPermissions and ApplicationPermissions is null

The azuread module as been deprecated. Try this script with the Microsoft.Graph module
$connected = Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All","Group.Read.All","Application.Read.All", "Application.Read.All", "Directory.Read.All" -NoWelcome

$apps = Get-MgApplication -All

$permissions = foreach($app in $apps){
    foreach($resource in $app.RequiredResourceAccess){
        $resourceSP = Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "AppId eq '$($resource.ResourceAppId)'"

        foreach($permission in $resource.ResourceAccess){
            if($permission.Type -eq 'Role'){
                $appRoleInfo = $resourceSP.AppRoles | where Id -eq $permission.Id
            
                [PSCustomObject] @{
                    AADAppName     = $app.DisplayName
                    AADAppId       = $app.AppId
                    PermissionType = "Application"
                    Resource       = $resourceSP.DisplayName
                    ResourceId     = $resourceSP.Id
                    Scope          = $appRoleInfo.Value
                    PrincipalType  = "Application"
                    UPN            = if($null -ne $userPrincipal){$userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName}else{"NA"}
                    PrincipalId    = if($null -ne $userPrincipal){$userPrincipal.Id}else{"NA"}
                    SignInAudience = $app.SignInAudience
                }
            }
            elseif ($permission.Type -eq 'Scope'){
                $scopes = $resourceSP.Oauth2PermissionScopes | where Id -eq $permission.Id
            
                [PSCustomObject] @{
                    AADAppName     = $app.DisplayName
                    AADAppId       = $app.AppId
                    PermissionType = "Delegated"
                    Resource       = $resourceSP.DisplayName
                    ResourceId     = $resourceSP.Id
                    Scope          = $scopes.Value
                    PrincipalType  = $scopes.Type
                    UPN            = if($null -ne $userPrincipal){$userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName}else{"NA"}
                    PrincipalId    = if($null -ne $userPrincipal){$userPrincipal.Id}else{"NA"}
                    SignInAudience = $app.SignInAudience
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$permissions | Format-Table -AutoSize

